# Minimum of uniformly convergent function sequence

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, uniform-convergence

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable. Assume that there is a sequence of continuously differentiable functions $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \|f - f_n\|_{L_\infty} = 0 .
$$

Moreover, let
$$
\xi := \text{arg}\min_{x \in [0,1]} f(x) \quad \text{ and } \xi_n := \text{arg}\min_{x \in [0,1]} f_n(x) .
$$

Is it true that it holds $\xi_n \to \xi$? If yes, why?

Or is it neccessary that the derivatives of $f_n$ converge uniformly to the derivatives of $f$ as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $f_n(x)=x^n(1-x)$ if $n$ is even, $f_n(x)=x(1-x)^n$ if $n$ is odd. For all $n$
$$
0\le f_n(x)\le\frac1n,\quad 0\le x\le1.
$$
We see that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$, but
$$
\xi_n=\begin{cases}\dfrac{n}{n+1} & \text{if $n$ is even,}\\
\dfrac{1}{n} & \text{if $n$ is odd.}\end{cases}
$$
Thus, $\xi_n$ does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

The counterexample is wrong, the argmin of $f_n$ is clearly x=0 or x=1 and since the limit function is the zero function all x are the argmin and argmax. The $\xi_n$ are actualy the argmax.
Furthermore I think that the original statement is true if the Limit function has a unique argmin but i have no reference.